# XML casting in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am working on XML validation using XSD files. Everything is working fine and it is returning the output as desired. Check the code below

```
public XmlValidatorResult Validate(Stream xml, Stream xsd)
{
    ClearErrorMessage();
    XmlValidatorResult result = new XmlValidatorResult();
    try
    {
        XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(xsd);
        schema.Add(null, tr);

        Stream stream = GetFileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/XML/SLFefileTypes.xsd"));
        XmlTextReader tr2 = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        schema.Add(null, tr2);

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.Schemas.Add(schema);

        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ErrorHandler);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xml, settings);

        // Validate XML data
        while (reader.Read());
        reader.Close();

        // exception if validation failed
        if (numErrors > 0)
            throw new Exception(msgError);

        result.HasValidated = true;
        result.ErrorInfo = null;
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Exception Handler**

```
private void ErrorHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    XmlReader r = (XmlReader)sender;
    IXmlLineInfo lineInfo = sender as IXmlLineInfo;

    object aa = (XmlSchemaValidationException)args;

    string error = "\r\n" + "Line Number - " + lineInfo.LineNumber + " Line Position - " + lineInfo.LinePosition + "\n" + args.Message;
    msgError = msgError + error;

    ErrorInfo.Add(error);

    numErrors++;
}
```

Now if you will see closely in the handler code there is a line

```
object aa = (XmlSchemaValidationException)args;
```

where i am tring to cast the exception to **XmlSchemaValidationException** class to get the **SourceObject**. But it is showing me following error.

> Cannot convert type 'System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs' to
>   'System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException'

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why is this question flagged as vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast the `ValidationEventArgs`, which *isn't* the exception - that's why the cast is failing.

I suspect you just need to use the `Exception` property, which is of type `XmlSchemaException` - that isn't `XmlSchemaValidationException`, but you can cast *that*:

```
private void ErrorHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    var exception = (XmlSchemaValidationException) args.Exception;
    object sourceObject = exception.SourceObject;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That's ok but I have to get the SourceObject which resides under XmlSchemaValidationException class. I want to do something like this object aa = ((XmlSchemaValidationException)args).SourceObject;

Comment: This question was answered here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc10c85a-97fa-4ee6-af36-79cd4371590a/how-to-get-current-node-while-validate-xml-document-with-xsd?forum=xmlandnetfx but actually they have not posted how to cast.

Comment: @AbhishekK.Upadhyay: No, you really *don't* want to do that cast, because `args` itself is not the exception. You want to cast the exception instead. I've edited my answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: @AbhishekK.Upadhyay: Note that even in the conversation you referenced, it explained how to do it: "In the latter case I think you can cast **the Exception property** of the ValidationEventArgs parameter" (emphasis mine).

Comment: I have tried your code but it is giving a null value in SourceObject.

Comment: @AbhishekK.Upadhyay: Then it isn't being populated in the exception. If the cast worked, that proves the exception was the right type. You should look into what might cause `SourceObject` not to be populated, but that's really a different question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This exception is from Microsoft https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dddebd26-5542-42f3-b15f-9dd2257f1377/xmlschemavalidationexceptionsourceobject-is-always-null-when-using-xpathnavigatorcheckvalidity?forum=xmlandnetfx.